# Wake up a sleeping thread, else sleep for N seconds

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am writing a C program using POSIX threads.

Let N be a global variable. I have a thread that calls sleep(N). A different thread then changes the value of N. How can I have my original thread that called sleep(N) wake up, and call sleep again on the new value of N?

To rephrase, I want to sleep for N, if N gets updated, wake up, and sleep for the new value of N.

<strike>I have looked into pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_timedwait, but I do not think it is useful in my case, as I would need the threads to be asleep for a specific amount of time. I need my thread to continuously sleep and wake up every N seconds.</strike>

As user1930928 showed below, I think I need to use pthread_cond_timedwait

Comment: Try [`pthread_cond_timedwait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html#tag_16_420), and ask another question if that proves troublesome.

Comment: didn't get you a bit, do you want to make thread sleep for updated N value?

Comment: Yes, either sleep for N, or if N gets updated, wake up and sleep for the new value of N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question and the objective is stil not clear to me...but let me provide a code skeleton so that you can clarify your question better.

```
Initialize N.
Initialize mutex.
Initialize CV.

T1()
{
    mutex_lock();
    while (1) {
        copy_of_N = N;       
        pthread_cond_timedwait(N); // drops the mutex
        ....
        ....

        // timed wait done OR wakeup was issued on cond var
        if (copy_of_N != N) {
            // N was changed
            do_something();
        } else {
            // N was not changed
            do_something_else();
        }

        // either way, goto sleep on N.                   
    }
    mutex_unlock();
}

T2()
{
    mutex_lock();
    change N;
    pthread_cond_signal();
    mutex_unlock();
}
```

Please clarify your question based on whether the above skeleton matches your req or not.

Comment: Yes this what I wanted. Clearly I was not understanding pthread_cond_timedwait. Anyway you can turn this into actual code?